# Does QEMU support emulation of PowerPC CPUs MPC5510 and/or MPC5566?

Tags: qemu, emulation, powerpc, microprocessors

Does QEMU support PowerPC MPC5510 and/or MPC5566?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. No QEMU does not support Powerpc MPC5510/MCP5566. Command:

```
qemu-system-ppc -cpu ?
```

... lists supported CPUs.

Comment: This is a flawed method insufficient to answer the question *in the negative*, as it queries only your particular binary build of unspecified version and configuration settings, or at most the documentation current whenever that was compiled.  A sound method would be to check the source repository, development mailing list, etc.  One would also need to know enough details of the chip to tell if anything supported is within a few configuration settings of matching.